# Test if a SOAP WSDL is up or down in vb script?

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, vba

I am trying to Verify if the WSDL is UP and Running or NOT in VB Script.

IF we open the WSDL in browser, if we get an XML in that then the WSDL is UP and Running

If it is blank/timing out/not responding then WSDL is DOWN

I want to write a VB Script program for this?

I was expecting some thing like this in VB Script to run in QTP/UFT or EXCEL VBA MACRO.

This program is written in Java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String wsdl = "http://lxomavnat005.dev.qintra.com:10301/icl/services/ICL_2_0?wsdl";
    URL url = null;
    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {

        url = new URL(wsdl);
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        if (urlConnection.getContent() != null) {
            System.out.println("GOOD URL");
        } else {
            System.out.println("BAD URL");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out
                .println("Failed opening connection. Perhaps WS is not up?");
    }
}
```

This Program just check the content is loading or not and decides if it running or not

Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.
I tested using a SharePoint 2010 web service.

```
' TestWSDL - Test if WSDL is up and running
Public Sub TestWSDL()
  Dim oHttpRequest As Object
  Dim oHttpResponse As Object

  On Error GoTo Trap

  Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  oHttpRequest.Open "GET", "http://domain/path/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?wsdl", False
  oHttpRequest.Send

  If oHttpRequest.ReadyState = 4 Then
    If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
      Set oHttpResponse = oHttpRequest.ResponseXML
      If oHttpResponse Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "bad url"
      Else
        MsgBox "good url"
        Set oHttpResponse = Nothing
      End If
    Else
      MsgBox oHttpRequest.Status & " - " & oHttpRequest.StatusText
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox oHttpRequest.ReadyState
  End If

Trap:
  If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Error(Err)
  End If

  Set oHttpRequest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Following is similar, using [Microsoft WinHTTP Services v5.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of Microsoft XMLHTTP

```
Public Sub TestWinHTTP()
  Dim oHttpRequest As Object

  On Error GoTo Trap

  Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
  oHttpRequest.Open "GET", "http://domain/path/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?wsdl", False

  ' Need to use SetCredentials OR SetAutoLogonPolicy
  ' Set specific username / password
  'oHttpRequest.SetCredentials "username", "password", 0

  ' Use windows authentication
  oHttpRequest.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0

  ' Set timeout values -- host, connect, send, receive
  oHttpRequest.SetTimeouts 30000, 60000, 30000, 30000

  oHttpRequest.Send

  If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
    If oHttpRequest.ResponseText = "" Then
      MsgBox "bad url"
    Else
      MsgBox "good url"
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "bad url"
  End If

Trap:
  If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Error(Err)
  End If

  Set oHttpRequest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Seems a huge code.See the code in Java and help me in VB

Comment: check the edit, broke it down for you, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Excellent Work Buddy :)  But i just wanted to know what is the exact error message we will get  If oHttpRequest.ReadyState is not  4 and If oHttpRequest.Status is not  200 instead putting a bad URL

Comment: cheers! see edit for `Status` and `ReadyState`, along with any specific error message...

Comment: I have a Question, This Program works well but when the WSDL keeps on LOADING in the browser, the programs is not responding , then i need to terminate it manually. i created the MACRO with list of wsdls i have and i am running one by one and getting the status , if one of the wsdl is keep on loading , the macro gets hanged and i need to terminate the process and restart it. do we have any solution for this kind of situations and proceed for next wsdl in the list after some timeout ?

Comment: take a look at the reference for [`Microsoft.XMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx) -- you can set your own `timeout` value, there is also an `abort` method, which may help...

Comment: HI bro, Can you please help me in putting this. i tried and i am getting error like object doesn't support. I am getting error at line 3

 Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
              oHttpRequest.Open "GET", WSDL, False
              oHttpRequest.timeout = 30 *1000
              oHttpRequest.Send

Comment: Ok i will wait for you reply bro

Comment: Sorry, forgot to get back to you. XMLHTTP does *not* have a `timeout` property when instantiated from Excel. The reference link above must be specific to Internet Explorer only. However, you can also use WinHTTP. I have added an example to the answer, hope it helps. Note the need to set credentials or logon policy...

Comment: Thanks Bro that helped :)