# How to login in Office 365 from VBScript and browse through sharepoint with pascal script(?)

Tags: vbscript, sharepoint-2013, office365, pascalscript

I'm packing an Access application, This is connecting with a Sharepoint site. I'm using Inno Setup (With Pascal Scripts) for create an install package. So,
I found this code for do something similar to that I want, when I run the code seems work fine: Open the browser, goes to Office 365, puts information (account and password), but just in the moment when open the cmd and after few seconds, all closes without finish the process.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application.1")
Call objIE.Navigate("https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(500) : Loop

objIE.Document.all.Login.Value = "username@yourdomain.com"
objIE.Document.all.Passwd.Value = "office365password"
objIE.Document.all.persist.checked=True

'The "Submit" button needs to be "clicked" twice in order to sign the user in
' * It appears that some javascript needs to take place behind the scenes to properly initiate the logon
Call objIE.Document.getElementById("cred_sign_in_button").click
Call objIE.Document.getElementById("cred_sign_in_button").click

WScript.Sleep(4000)

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(500) : Loop

Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

NetCommand="net.exe use p: ""https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/Library 1""  /user:username@yourdomain.com office365password"
wShell.Run "cmd.exe /C " & NetCommand, 1, True

Set wShell=Nothing

objIE.quit

Set objIE = Nothing
```

Seems to maybe can be here:

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

NetCommand="net.exe use p: ""https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/Library 1""  /user:username@yourdomain.com office365password"
wShell.Run "cmd.exe /C " & NetCommand, 1, True
```

**My final aim** is do the all process of login in the backstage (for code), create the connexion with 365 via (VBScript (?)), providing the credentials in the script, thereupon go a list in sharepoint site, title: (Serial Numbers(?)) where I Have a list with several numbers and checkboxes for to mark true in every install and avoid use the same number two times.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: trying to understand _final aim_ a little better, sounds like you need to update a SharePoint list? and you're trying to automate IE to do that for you?

Comment: Hi & thanks for your answer. I'm not sure. Firstly I need to automate the login to SharePoint site from some script, because I dont want to give the credentials to each client, but my application works connect to SharePoint, on the other hand, I need to navigate through the site using Inno Setup for use some list during the install process. Is it more clear now?

Comment: sorry, not really. what specific actions need to be taken within SharePoint? my point is, there are APIs like [Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193051.aspx) and [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) that allow you to login and perform actions via code/script directly, which would be much simpler than trying to control IE...

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat. I developed an application in ms-access which is linked with several lists in my sharepoint site but when I distribute this application, ms-access asks for the credentials and I must to give them, after ms-access remembers this credentials and works without problems. My problem is that I can't do all installations. For this reason I am trying to make a install package and during the installation give this the credentials.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know much about web services, however I'm reading the links you gave me. Now, what do you think? Do you think that the better way be using a web service? If you think there is the way, Do you have more information about how can I do what I want? Thanks so much!

Comment: ok, I think I get it, thank you. However, I'm struggling with how an API might be able to do this any better. For what it's worth, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33393856/5090771) are two examples of how to connect with a web service in VBA. The second example shows how to `SetCredentials`.